# Festival of ASCII-art lights

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, date

Write, in as few **characters** as possible, a program that takes zero or six command-line arguments

```
menorah
menorah YEAR MONTH DAY HOUR MINUTE SECOND
```

(Both forms must be supported.  The zero-argument version shall be equivalent to calling the six-argument version with the *current* system date and time in the local timezone.)

and if the specified (Gregorian-calendar) date and time falls during [Hanukkah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanukkah), then output an ASCII art (or Unicode art) nine-branch menorah with the appropriate number of candles lit.  If it is *not* during Hanukkah, then output a single newline.  For example,

```
~$ ./menorah 2015 12 7 0 0 0

    *
    |   *
    |   |
    |   |
+++++++++
    |
   -+-

~$ ./menorah 2015 12 9 0 0 0

    *
    | ***
    | |||
    | |||
+++++++++
    |
   -+-

~$ ./menorah 2015 12 14 0 0 0

    *
****|****
|||||||||
|||||||||
+++++++++
    |
   -+-

~$ ./menorah 2015 12 15 0 0 0
~$
```

On the Nth day of the festival, N+1 candles are lit: The central *shamash* candle, and N of the 8 Hanukkah candles, placed in right-to-left order.

Allowed variations in the output format are:

- Unused candles may be drawn unlit instead of omitted.
- You may use non-ASCII characters to make the result more aesthetically pleasing.  Like  (U+1F525) instead of `*`.  Or box-drawing characters instead of `+-|`.

For the purpose of this challenge, a day on the Hebrew calendar may be assumed to start at 18:00.

Results must be correct for Gregorian years between 1900 and 2239, inclusive.

---

Hanukkah begins at **sunset** on the Gregorian dates

```
1900-12-16  1901-12-05  1902-12-24  1903-12-13  1904-12-02  1905-12-22
1906-12-11  1907-11-30  1908-12-18  1909-12-07  1910-12-25  1911-12-15
1912-12-04  1913-12-23  1914-12-12  1915-12-01  1916-12-19  1917-12-09
1918-11-28  1919-12-16  1920-12-05  1921-12-25  1922-12-14  1923-12-02
1924-12-21  1925-12-11  1926-11-30  1927-12-18  1928-12-07  1929-12-26
1930-12-14  1931-12-04  1932-12-23  1933-12-12  1934-12-01  1935-12-20
1936-12-08  1937-11-28  1938-12-17  1939-12-06  1940-12-24  1941-12-14
1942-12-03  1943-12-21  1944-12-10  1945-11-29  1946-12-17  1947-12-07
1948-12-26  1949-12-15  1950-12-03  1951-12-23  1952-12-12  1953-12-01
1954-12-19  1955-12-09  1956-11-28  1957-12-17  1958-12-06  1959-12-25
1960-12-13  1961-12-02  1962-12-21  1963-12-10  1964-11-29  1965-12-18
1966-12-07  1967-12-26  1968-12-15  1969-12-04  1970-12-22  1971-12-12
1972-11-30  1973-12-19  1974-12-08  1975-11-28  1976-12-16  1977-12-04
1978-12-24  1979-12-14  1980-12-02  1981-12-20  1982-12-10  1983-11-30
1984-12-18  1985-12-07  1986-12-26  1987-12-15  1988-12-03  1989-12-22
1990-12-11  1991-12-01  1992-12-19  1993-12-08  1994-11-27  1995-12-17
1996-12-05  1997-12-23  1998-12-13  1999-12-03  2000-12-21  2001-12-09
2002-11-29  2003-12-19  2004-12-07  2005-12-25  2006-12-15  2007-12-04
2008-12-21  2009-12-11  2010-12-01  2011-12-20  2012-12-08  2013-11-27
2014-12-16  2015-12-06  2016-12-24  2017-12-12  2018-12-02  2019-12-22
2020-12-10  2021-11-28  2022-12-18  2023-12-07  2024-12-25  2025-12-14
2026-12-04  2027-12-24  2028-12-12  2029-12-01  2030-12-20  2031-12-09
2032-11-27  2033-12-16  2034-12-06  2035-12-25  2036-12-13  2037-12-02
2038-12-21  2039-12-11  2040-11-29  2041-12-17  2042-12-07  2043-12-26
2044-12-14  2045-12-03  2046-12-23  2047-12-12  2048-11-29  2049-12-19
2050-12-09  2051-11-28  2052-12-15  2053-12-05  2054-12-25  2055-12-14
2056-12-02  2057-12-21  2058-12-10  2059-11-29  2060-12-17  2061-12-07
2062-12-26  2063-12-15  2064-12-03  2065-12-22  2066-12-12  2067-12-01
2068-12-18  2069-12-08  2070-11-27  2071-12-16  2072-12-04  2073-12-24
2074-12-13  2075-12-01  2076-12-20  2077-12-10  2078-11-29  2079-12-17
2080-12-06  2081-12-26  2082-12-15  2083-12-04  2084-12-22  2085-12-11
2086-11-30  2087-12-19  2088-12-07  2089-11-27  2090-12-16  2091-12-05
2092-12-23  2093-12-13  2094-12-02  2095-12-20  2096-12-09  2097-11-29
2098-12-18  2099-12-06  2100-12-26  2101-12-16  2102-12-05  2103-12-23
2104-12-12  2105-12-02  2106-12-21  2107-12-10  2108-11-28  2109-12-17
2110-12-06  2111-12-25  2112-12-13  2113-12-03  2114-12-22  2115-12-10
2116-11-29  2117-12-19  2118-12-08  2119-12-26  2120-12-15  2121-12-04
2122-12-23  2123-12-12  2124-12-01  2125-12-21  2126-12-10  2127-11-29
2128-12-17  2129-12-06  2130-12-24  2131-12-14  2132-12-03  2133-12-22
2134-12-11  2135-11-30  2136-12-18  2137-12-07  2138-12-26  2139-12-15
2140-12-04  2141-12-23  2142-12-12  2143-12-01  2144-12-20  2145-12-09
2146-11-27  2147-12-17  2148-12-05  2149-12-24  2150-12-13  2151-12-03
2152-12-22  2153-12-11  2154-11-30  2155-12-19  2156-12-07  2157-12-25
2158-12-15  2159-12-05  2160-12-23  2161-12-12  2162-12-01  2163-12-20
2164-12-09  2165-11-28  2166-12-16  2167-12-06  2168-12-24  2169-12-13
2170-12-02  2171-12-22  2172-12-10  2173-11-28  2174-12-18  2175-12-08
2176-12-26  2177-12-14  2178-12-04  2179-12-24  2180-12-12  2181-12-01
2182-12-20  2183-12-09  2184-11-28  2185-12-17  2186-12-06  2187-12-25
2188-12-14  2189-12-03  2190-12-21  2191-12-11  2192-11-29  2193-12-17
2194-12-07  2195-12-27  2196-12-15  2197-12-03  2198-12-23  2199-12-13
2200-12-02  2201-12-20  2202-12-10  2203-11-30  2204-12-18  2205-12-07
2206-12-26  2207-12-15  2208-12-03  2209-12-22  2210-12-11  2211-12-01
2212-12-19  2213-12-08  2214-12-27  2215-12-17  2216-12-05  2217-12-23
2218-12-13  2219-12-02  2220-12-20  2221-12-09  2222-11-29  2223-12-18
2224-12-05  2225-12-25  2226-12-15  2227-12-04  2228-12-21  2229-12-11
2230-12-01  2231-12-20  2232-12-08  2233-12-27  2234-12-16  2235-12-05
2236-12-23  2237-12-12  2238-12-02  2239-12-21
```

Comment: For those of us who are not Jewish (and for those who are but don't know how to calculate the Jewish calendar) please explain how the start of Hanukkah is calculated. You should also explain the sequence of lighting the candles (it seems to be one per day, but does it matter which candle you light? )

Comment: Are we required to support *both* zero and six command-line arguments, or can we choose?

Comment: @ThomasKwa: Both.  The difference is that the zero-argument version uses the *current* date and time.

Comment: @steveverrill: I've added a list of the relevant Gregorian-calendar dates.  The calendar itself is based on the 19-year Metonic cycle.

Comment: Can STDIN be used for languages that don't have command line arguments?

Comment: @xnor: Yes.  If your language doesn't support command-line arguments, you may have the user enter the values at runtime (whether through STDIN or through GUI objects).

Comment: @GamrCorps I'm casting a reopen vote, as the concerns I had when I cast the first closevote have been addressed. If there is something outstanding, please indicate what it is. Otherwise please don't pile on close votes after the problem is solved. Dan04, Ok I see you have added the list. I had to look up Metonic. So it means the lunar and solar cycles coincide once every 19 years. But not exactly, it seems there is a random(ish) variation by a +/-day every 19 year period.

Comment: Beware that drawing unused candles as unlit will be much easier (and I think less interesting) than drawing them as missing.

Comment: the option to draw unused candles as unlit means the dynamic ascii art portion of this is just one row of toggled asterisks, which is not interesting at all. not that I find the larger ascii art drawing particularly interesting to begin with.

Comment: @Sparr the ascii art portion is far from the most challenging part of this challenge at end, the conversion from gregorian to hebrew Date and checking if we're within the Holidays or not is far more interesting IMO

Comment: There is little or no incentive to do the "Aesthetically pleasing" challenge, as it will merely increase bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Mathematica, <s>376</s> <s>338</s> 334 bytes

```
a=Rest@$ScriptCommandLine;b=CalendarConvert[If[a=={},Now~TimeZoneConvert~0,DateObject[FromDigits/@a,TimeZone->0]],j="Jewish"];c=Floor@DateDifference[DateObject[{b[[1,1]],9,25},CalendarType->j,TimeZone->0],b][[1]];d=If[#<=c,"*"," "]&;0<=c<8&&Print["    *
"<>{d/@{7,6,5,4},"|",d/@{3,2,1},"*
|||||||||
|||||||||
+++++++++
    |
   -+-"}]
```

Runs in a script.

Answer (score 3):

### R, 467 bytes

With a little doubt if using a library for the Calendar conversion is allowed or not.

```
library(ConvCalendar)
f='%Y %m %d %H %M %S'
g='hebrew'
s=' '
if(length(n<-scan())!=6)n=format(Sys.time(),f)
if(n[4]>17)n[3]=n[3]+1
d=strptime(paste(n,collapse=s),f)
h=as.OtherDate(d,g)
i=OtherDate(25,3,h$year,g)
j=round(difftime(d,as.Date(i),,"days"))+1
N=ifelse(j>0&j<10,(1:9)[j],0)
if(!N)write('')else{l='**||+|+'
z=matrix(strsplit(l,'')[[1]],9,7,T)
z[c(1:4,6:9),c(1,6:7)]=s
z[c(4,6),7]='-'
if(N<8)z[1:(9-N),2:4]=s
z[5,2:4]='|'
write(z,'',9,,'')}
```

Example for input 2015 12 07 00 00 00:

```
    *    
    |   *
    |   |
    |   |
+++++++++
    |    
   -+-
```

Comment: My eyes........ :)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 193 bytes

Prompts for input from STDIN and prints to STDOUT.

Uses box drawing characters and an [actual lamp symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_syntax_and_symbols#Miscellaneous)!

```apl
⎕USING←'System'
→3×(c←+/i≥((⎕NEW Globalization.HebrewCalendar).(ToDateTime 7↑3 23 18,⍨GetYear)i←⎕NEW DateTime(6↑⍎∊⍞'⎕TS')).AddDays¨⍳9)∊⍳8
¯5↑'⍝'
'⍝'@(10-r+5≤r←⍳c)⊢9↑s←¯5↑'│'
9/⍪'││┴'
s
'   ─┴─'
```

`⎕USING←'System'` Use .NET

`⍳8` first eight **ɩ**ntegers
`(`…`)∊` Boolean for whether the following is a member of that:
 `⍳9` first nine integers
 `(`…`).AddDays¨` for each, add that many days to:
  `⎕NEW DateTime(`…`)` a new DateTime .NET object with the value of:
   `⍞'⎕TS'` STDIN and expression for current **T**ime **S**tamp
   `∊` **ϵ**nlist (flatten)
   `⍎` execute (evaluate) that (gives six- or seven-element numeric list)
   `6↑` take the first six elements (Y M D h m s)
  `i←` store as `i` (for **i**nput)
  `(⎕NEW Globalization.HebrewCalendar).(`…`)` in a new HebrewCalendar object:
   `GetYear` get the (Hebrew) year of the input
   `3 23 18,⍨` append these (3 month, 23<sup>th</sup> day, 18<sup>th</sup> hour — one night before Hanukkah)
   `7↑` take the first seven elements, padding with 0s (minutes, seconds)
   `ToDateTime` convert that Hebrew point in time to normal DateTime object
 `i≥` Boolean whether the input is equal to or after each of those
 `+/` sum the Booleans
 `c←` store as `c` (for **c**ount)
`3×` multiply by three
`→` go to that line (3, i.e. next, if Hanukkah; 0, i.e. quit, if not)

`¯5↑'⍝'` implicitly print the last five characters of the lamp symbol (padding with spaces)

`¯5↑'│'` last five characters of the middle-candle symbol (padding with spaces)
`s←` store as s (for **s**tem)
`9↑` take the first nine characters from that (padding with spaces)
`⊢` yield (separates the above from the below
`'⍝'@(`…`)` implicitly print with lamps placed at the following indices:
 `⍳c` as many **ɩ**ntegers as count of begun Hanukkah days
 `r←` store in `r` (for **r**ange)
 `5≤` Booleans for those larger than or equal to five (to skip the middle candle)
 `r+` add to the range of indices
 `10-` subtract those from ten (to begin at the right)

`⍪'││┴'` make this string into a column matrix
`9/` implicitly print nine horizontal copies of that

`s` implicitly print the stem

`'   ─┴─'` implicitly print this string

#### Example run:

```apl
      menorah
2015 12 7 0 0 0
    ⍝
    │   ⍝
│││││││││
│││││││││
┴┴┴┴┴┴┴┴┴
    │
   ─┴─
      menorah
2015 12 9 0 0 0
    ⍝
    │ ⍝⍝⍝
│││││││││
│││││││││
┴┴┴┴┴┴┴┴┴
    │
   ─┴─
      menorah
2015 12 14 0 0 0
    ⍝
⍝⍝⍝⍝│⍝⍝⍝⍝
│││││││││
│││││││││
┴┴┴┴┴┴┴┴┴
    │
   ─┴─
      menorah
2015 12 15 0 0 0
```